# Pandas: sorting a dataframe in subgroups, issue with sorting equal values

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I am trying to solve the following problem.
I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id2', 'id2','id2', 'id2', 'id2','id2', 'id3', 'id3', 'id3'] ,
                   'B': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21] , 
                 'C': [101 , 32, 10, 9, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 40, 36, 36]} )
df

Out[16]: 
      A   B    C
0   id1  10  101
1   id1  11   32
2   id2  12   10
3   id2  13    9
4   id2  14   15
5   id2  15   15
6   id2  16   15
7   id2  17   15
8   id2  18   15
9   id3  19   40
10  id3  20   36
11  id3  21   36
```

I now wish to rearrange the dataframe such that the values in column `C` are sorted in ascending order for each subgroup defined by the id values in column `A`. I use the following piece of code:

```
df2 = df
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['A','C'], ascending=True).groupby('A').head()
```

and I get this:

```
df2
Out[18]: 
      A   B    C
1   id1  11   32
0   id1  10  101
3   id2  13    9
2   id2  12   10
4   id2  14   15
5   id2  15   15
6   id2  16   15
10  id3  20   36
11  id3  21   36
9   id3  19   40
```

The values in `C` corresponding to the subgroup `id1` in col `A` have been all sorted correctly, as well as those values corresponding to the subgroup `id3`. However, the sorting operation of col `C` relative to `id2` in col `A` has skipped two rows...

```
print len(df.index), len(df2.index)
12 10
```

Any idea why does this happen and how to fix this issue?
Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
MarcoC

Comment: `head()` by default  gets top 5 values.

Comment: Thank you @Jarad. Indeed, that is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need only [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df2=df.sort_values(by=['A','C'], ascending=True)
print (df2)
      A   B    C
1   id1  11   32
0   id1  10  101
3   id2  13    9
2   id2  12   10
4   id2  14   15
5   id2  15   15
6   id2  16   15
7   id2  17   15
8   id2  18   15
10  id3  20   36
11  id3  21   36
9   id3  19   40
```

And you remove rows, because by default `head(5)` - get only top `5` rows per group.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. The sorting command was wrong in the first place, did not need to `groupby`, and did not need `head()`.

Answer (score 2):

Because of your `.groupby('A').head()`. `.head` just displays the first 5 rows of a DataFrame. It is returning just the first 5 rows of the group 'id2'. Remove the `.head` and you will get the right answer:

```
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['A','C'], ascending=True).groupby('A') # Note, no .head()
print len(df.index), len(df2.index)
12 12
```